# Naming a dataframe like the path

Tags: r, tidyverse, standardized

I have a lot of CSV that need to be standardized. I created a dictionary for doing so and so far the function that I have looks like this:

```
inputpath <- ("input")

files<- paste0(inputpath, "/", 
                 list.files(path = inputpath, pattern = '*.gz',
                            full.names = FALSE))

standardizefunctiontofiles = lapply(files, function(x){
    DF <- read_delim(x, delim = "|",  na="")
    names(DF) <- dictionary$final_name[match(names(DF), dictionary$old_name)]
})
```

Nonetheless, the issue that I have is that when I read the CSV and turn them into a dataframe they lose their path and therefore I can't not write each of them as a CSV that matches the input name. What I would normally do would be:

```
output_name <- str_replace(x, "input", "output")
write_delim(x, "output_name", delim = "|")
```

I was thinking that a way of solving this would be to make this step:

```
DF <- read_delim(x, delim = "|",  na="")
```

so that the DF gets the name of the path but I haven't find any solution for that.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue for being able to apply a function and writing each of them as a standardized CSV?

Answer (score 0):

I don't completely understand the question. But as far as I understood you want to overwrite CSV files you are reading with a new CSV file that contains the information of a modified (and correct) data frame.

I think you have two alternatives

Option 1) When reading data, store both CSV as a data frame and path as a string within a list.

This would be something like

```
file_list <- list()

for (i in seq_along(files)) {
  file_list[[i]] <- list(df = read_delim(files[[i]], delim = "|",  na = ""),
                         path = files[[i]])
}
```

Then, when you write the corrected data frames, you can use the paths in the second element of the list within the list `file_list`. Note that in order to get the path as a string you will need to do something like `file_list[[1]][["path"]]`

Option 2) Use `assign`

```
for (i in seq_along(files)) {
   assign(files[[i]], read_delim(files[[i]], delim = "|",  na = ""))
}
```

Option 3) Use `do.call` and the fact that `<-` is a function!

```
for (i in seq_along(files)) {
   do.call("<-", list(files[[i]], read_delim(files[[i]], delim = "|",  na = "")))
}
```

I hope this is useful!!

NB) None of the functions are implemented as efficiently as possible. They just introduce the idea.